# Angular 8 - How to intercept an http error inside a from (rxjs)?

Tags: angular, typescript

My interceptor looks like follows:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let tokenPromise = this.storage.get('token');

    return from(tokenPromise).pipe(mergeMap(token => {
      let data = {
        headers: request.headers.set('MyToken', token)
      };
      let newReq = request.clone(data);
      return next.handle(newReq);
    }));

}
```

How can I also intercept 404 errors?

Comment: https://medium.com/@antwaneb/catch-and-handle-all-404-errors-from-your-webservice-in-angular-5-2269b717d78f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that HttpClient returns an Observable, so you handle the errors as you would to any other observable - using [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html).

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let tokenPromise = this.storage.get('token');
    return from(tokenPromise).pipe(
       mergeMap(token => {...}),
       catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (error.status === 404) {
             // some logic
          }
          return throwError(error);
       })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(catchError((err) => {
        if (err.status === 404) {
          // do things
        }
    }));
  }
}
```

And your app.module, in providers:

```
{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true}
```